# Oracle tablespace can I drop all files

Tags: oracle

I am trying drop the temp tables space it has three files

```
/tmp/TEMPRM/create/TEMPRM/datafile/o1_mf_temprm_t_bw3t4zkp_.tmp
+TEMPDATA/rm/datafile/temprm_tempfile_1.dbf
+TEMPDATA/rm/datafile/temprm_tempfile_2.dbf
```

Before dropping table space I want to delete all  the file, I am able to remove the first two files last one gives the error.

```
 SQL> SQL> ALTER  TABLESPACE TEMPRM_TEMP DROP TEMPFILE '+TEMPDATA/rm/datafile/temprm_tempfile_2.dbf'
 *
 ERROR at line 1:
 ORA-03261: the tablespace TEMPRM_TEMP has only one file
```

If it is not allowed to delete all the files in table space, How to clean the table space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make a tablespace file-less. You can however drop a tablespace and it's datafiles in one statement:

```
DROP TABLESPACE temp_tablespace including contents and datafiles;
```

Make sure that you have a new temporary tablespace and make it the default before you drop the old one. Follow the below link for an example:

http://dbatricksworld.com/how-to-create-temporary-tablespace-and-drop-existing-temprary-tablespace-in-oracle-11g/

Comment: please note dropping the connected session is important (atleast in 12cr1 ), otherwise the drop statement just hangs.

Answer (score 0):

create a new temp tablespace, make this the default for the users. Once there are no connections using the old temp tablespace you should be able to drop the old temp tablespace

Comment: 'TEMPRM_TEMP' is not default TS , Default TS 'TEMP'